# DNS Update using TSIG error

Tags: dns

I'm trying to use nsupdate with TSIG and I'm getting the following error:

```
output: ; TSIG error with server: tsig indicates error
output: update failed: NOTAUTH(BADKEY)
```

I have reviewed all the setup, but I didn't managed to found anything wrong. The key was generated and inserted into the named.conf file as show below:

```
include "/etc/bind/ddns.atcbsb.net.br";

zone "ddns.atcbsb.net.br" in {
              type master;
              file "/etc/bind/ddns.actsbs";
              allow-query { any; };
              allow-transfer { node; };
              allow-update { key "atcbsb.net.br."; };
    };
```

My key is the shown below:

```
key "atcbsb.net.br." {
      algorithm hmac-md5;
      secret "qXPE6boHrFAy6lMu29SmNg==";
};
```

I checked the key in both *.key and *.private files and they are the same. Any help will be appreciated.

Marcio